# decimal separator in Estonian(et-EE) locale is coming as dot instead of comma in windows server

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, windows, localization

When I'm trying to find the decimal separator for a particular locale called Estonian Estonia(et-EE) by using below code, it's coming as dot instead of comma(only in Windows server) but in my local windows machine it's coming as comma, which is the correct decimal separator for this locale. Can anyone help me how can I get proper decimal separator for this locale?

```
CultureInfo cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("et-EE");
String decimalSeparator = cultureInfo.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator;
```

Comment: my local is in windows 10 and the windows server is "Windows Server 2012 R2"

Comment: Default culture on my local is en-US. Also, in the above code, I am explicitly mentioning a culture and trying to get the decimal separator for that particular culture. I am not getting how current thread culture would affect that.

Comment: What user account is IIS running under? (and please add the details to your post rather than as comments)

Answer (score 0):

Your example code does not change any formatting settings...

As long you do not provide a culture info to your formatting functions or as long you do not change the System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture, this will be the case.

So if your default culture is the Estonian on your local machine that setting will be right. On a server, it will be more likely a generic culture,  you should overwrite the current culture either by changing the System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture or you can set it in the web.config as stated here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for this question as for this locale et-EE, CurrencyDecimalSeparator gives dot and NumberDecimalSeparator gives comma in windows server, but in local windows machine, both gives comma only.